# open a lightbox2 containing a flowplayer video from a menu link

Tags: routes, files, javascript

Is it possible to make a link from a main menu to open a [lightbox2](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightbox2) that will contain a flv video?

I have flowplayer installed but not swf tools

I thought of doing it with javascript but I'm sure there is another way

Answer (score 1):

Add **rel="lightvideo"** tag, it will popup the video, It also have the option to set the size of the modal window, for more information see the readme.txt

```
<a href="#" rel="lightvideo">Google video example</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just add rel="lightbox" to the link that should do it?

Answer (score 0):

As was said before add the lightvideo tag to any link with the rel attribute, you can add the size like this. 
    rel="lightvideo[width:600px; height:500px;]"

Adding it to a standard drupal menu item is a bit more difficult as you need to narrow down which menu item you want to apply it to.
You could add it to the menu item with jQuery though, something like this:

```
$('.menu li a').attr('rel', 'lightvideo[width:600px; height:500px;]');
```

You'll need to narrow it down to the exact menu item you want, that will apply it to all of them.